# Running program as another user

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm trying to launch an application as another user in my program. Here's what my code looks like:

```
result = CreateProcessWithLogonW(username.c_str(),domain.c_str() , password.c_str(),
             LOGON_NETCREDENTIALS_ONLY, exePath.c_str() ,NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, &su_info, &pi);
```

This works perfectly fine. However I noticed when when I run my program using this method (`LOGON_NETCREDENTIALS_ONLY`) and look at my program in task manager it is shown to be run as the calling process not the user I expected. There are actually other problems with this kind of logon but to keep it simple let's focus on task manager behavior. So in order to fix this problem I changed the logon flags to `LOGON_WITH_PROFILE`:

```
result = CreateProcessWithLogonW(username.c_str(),domain.c_str() , password.c_str(),
             LOGON_WITH_PROFILE, exePath.c_str() ,NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, &su_info, &pi);
```

But now I creating process fails and error code 1326 (The user name or password is incorrect) is returned.
Why is this happening? How do I run my executable as another user and actually see it being run as that user even in the task manager?

**EDIT:**
More debugging showed that the program works fine if I run the program normally. However if I run my program as post-build event (to run my tests) this type of logon fails.

Answer (score 1):

When you look at the MSDN page for [CreateProcessWithLogon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682431%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it specifically says (emphasis mine):

> LOGON_NETCREDENTIALS_ONLY
>
> Log on, but use the specified credentials on the network only. The new process uses the same token as the caller, but the system creates a new logon session within LSA, and the process uses the specified credentials as the default credentials.
> This value can be used to create a process that uses a different set of credentials locally than it does remotely. This is useful in inter-domain scenarios where there is no trust relationship.
> **The system does not validate the specified credentials**. Therefore, the process can start, but it may not have access to network resources.

So that explains the behaviour you are seeing with the task manager, as well as provide a possible explanation of why the first method worked and the second did not.

Before proceeding to the second issue, could you verify that `LOGON_WITH_PROFILE` works correctly in the non-post-build case?

Comment: I can't believe I skipped the highlighted part every time I read that! And about the second issue, I have already checked that and as said in the edit section it works fine.